# Google Chrome blocking downloads from my site

Tags: google-chrome, download, malware

Google Chrome has started to block downloads from my website. I get

> MyApplication.application may harm your browsing experience, so
>   Chrome has blocked it.

The files on the website are clickonce installers for my own software, it is hosted on a virtual machine, that only myself and collegues have access to, I have verified the website through google's search console, but the issue persists.

I can download any file from Internet Explorer or Firefox, but can't from Chrome.

I'm at a bit of a loss as where to go from here.

My boss has advised that I cannot post a link to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by verifying the website using the google search tool.

[Google Search Tool - Verification](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification)

I then had to add the HTML verification file to my website and click the link on the Google Search to verify.

After about 12 hours the issue had been resolved.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have the same issue, although, if I upload an update for my application, Chrome blocks it again

Comment: Hi Ilya, I think you need to do this each time you update your website. It's a pain

Answer (score 0):

Follow the check list below or request a view by visiting the source and following WMT guildlines on Software.

> [***SOURCE***](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/168328?hl=en)
>
> If your site is flagged as containing malware or unwanted software,
>   you can request a malware or unwanted software review. Prepare for
>   your review
>
> You must first take action on your own site before requesting a
>   review.
>
> - Make sure your site is free from any infected code and content. See What is malware for more details.
> - Make sure your site does not serve binary malware or unwanted software downloads.
> - Make sure your site complies with the Webmaster Guidelines.