# Chrome blocks new downloads from my site even after site verification

Tags: google-chrome, block

Google Chrome blocks downloads of my .exe application from my site.

`App.exe may harm your computer, so Chrome has blocked it.`

I temporarily fixed this issue by conducting [website verification](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/) as suggested as an answer to [Google Chrome blocking downloads from my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85128/google-chrome-blocking-downloads-from-my-site), and after 12-15 hours downloads were fixed.

But I released an update for my application today, and Chrome blocks it again. I plan to bring updates each month, and each month it will be the new .exe assembly. How can I permanently disable this behavior? I lose users for my app. Is there a way to send file for pre-review by Google? Their documentation is not really helpful.

Comment: Does it help if you wrap the `.exe` in a zip archive?

Comment: No, it doesn't help if I pack with zip or rar. it only helps if I pack with 7z. But it's not very appealing

Comment: Does scanning your application with a online virusscanner like virustotal.com yield false positives?

Comment: Hi Feerrybig, no, it all clear. I have actually solved the issue (see my answer), although it requires waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue for the first time, I needed to follow the advice from the question [Google Chrome blocking downloads from my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85128/google-chrome-blocking-downloads-from-my-site) and go through verification process.

To fix an issue for all consequent file uploads, I needed to upload file into the server and try to download it with the latest version of Chrome. It should then automatically send file for analysis (or you should click "Send file for analysis" in the message box otherwise, if you are doing this for the first time). After ~15 hours (max 72 hours) file should be verified. In my case with regular exe updates, I put the file into publicly accessible directory on my server with any other name (app_verification.exe instead of app.exe) and wait till verification completes. As soon as it completes I rename app_verification.exe to app.exe and there is still no problem.

Also, ensure your file actually doesn't contain code that can be treaded like virus (using virustotal.com). Don't forget to digitally sign your exe with trusted certificate.